# Gravitational Force units

Tags: newtonian-gravity, units

In the formula $F=mg$, does the mass $m$ needs to be in $kg$? And what is exact value of $g$? I've tried with both and didn't worked.

Comment: If we don't have to have $F$ be in Newtons, then sure, but be prepared to *not* be able to use that result with many other terms. What do you mean by "both"?

Answer (score 3):

$g = 9.81$ m /s^2

$m$ can be in whatever units of mass you want as long as you convert the units properly. $kg$ would be an acceptable choice. This gives you $\frac{kg\cdot m}{s^2}$ which is the definition of a Netwon, the unit of force.

Don't confuse $m$ the algebraic variable for mass with $m$ the shorthand notation for meters.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the mass were measured in units of Gustavos while the acceleration were measured in units of Fultons per Fesbins squared.

Then, the force would be in units of Gustavo $\cdot$ Fultons per Fesbins squared.

However, the *dimensions* of the force would still be mass $\cdot$ length per time squared.

That is to say, the Gustavos unit of mass, the Fulton unit of length, and the Fesbin unit of time could be converted to kg, meter, and second respectively.

In [English (engineering) units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Engineering_units), the unit of mass is *[slugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28mass%29)*, the unit of length is *feet*, and the unit of time is *seconds*.  In these *units*,

$$g \approx 32 \frac{ft}{s^2}$$

while, in the metric system

$$g \approx 9.81 \frac{m}{s^2} $$